# Trying to reproduce output of PIL's resize image in C++

Tags: python, c++, opencv, python-imaging-library

I'm currently resizing a PIL image in python using

```
resized_image = pil_image.resize((128, 128), resample=Image.BILINEAR)
```

I want to resize the same image, using C++ and have the output be identical to the python version. I have tried using opencvs resize function like this

```
cv::GpuMat::src;
cv::GpuMat::dst;
cv::cuda::resize(src, dst, cv::Size(128, 128), NULL, NULL, cv::INTER_LINEAR);
```

But if I write both images to file and inspect them I see that the python version of the resized images is noticeably more blurred.

I'm looking for ways to faithfully reproduce the resized python image in C++, but I'm not sure what the best way to go about it is. First of all, I don't really understand why there's a discrepancy in the output, they use the same bilinear downsampling.

I tried inspecting the code in https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/PIL/Image.py, to see if it's calling a c-lib. But to be honest, I don't even understand how that resize method works. It looks like it just calls itself at the end without doing any resizing work.

Comment: This calls for trouble and is a bit broad. If you take the input from a jpg for example even the decoders *can* output different images. Then resizing probably takes more than some method (e.g. border-handling, although your description sounds like it's not the culprit here) and i'm ignoring potential GPU-differences (floating-point size and co). Why not use opencv too for the python part (and hope it's using the same core)? Or probably the least-trouble approach (depending on your task): outsource it all to imagemagick.

Comment: @Locus The python code delegates the calls to a [C implementation](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/07fa92ba5b08137c61689f200818a8e11fea05ff/_imaging.c#L1499).

Answer (score 0):

On GitHub you can find the code for Pillow resize in C++ at the repository https://github.com/zurutech/pillow-resize.

The code has been obtained extracting the relevant parts from the source code of Pillow,

Disclaimer: the library is developed by my team at Zuru Tech.